# Python: AA_EnableHighDpiScaling on Qt v5.15.2

Tags: python, qt, hdpi

On [this page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) I read that high DPI scaling is available since qt v5.6. But it doesn't seem to work for me:

> Python 3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> >>> from PyQt5 import Qt, QtCore
>
> >>> QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR
>
> **'5.15.2'**
>
> >>> hasattr(Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling')
>
> **False**

What am I missing?

I was expecting for

> >>> hasattr(Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling')

to return

> **True**

And my Qt app to be HDPI aware of course :-)

Thanx for reading, Emil

Answer (score 0):

Just looking in the wrong place.

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore
>>> QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR
'5.15.2'
>>> hasattr(QtCore.Qt, "AA_EnableHighDpiScaling")
True
```